# How to get RedisInsight working on Kubernetes with PersistentVolumeClaim instead of EmptyDir?

Tags: kubernetes, redis, redisinsights

How to get RedisInsight working with `PersistentVolumeClaim`s?

I installed RedisInsight following the [docs](https://docs.redis.com/latest/ri/installing/install-k8s/) and the Pod starts normally and is available via the created Service, if the `deployment.yaml` uses `emptyDir`. Therefore, my question differs from  [redisinsights-with-persistent-volume-in-kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62714925/redisinsights-with-persistent-volume-in-kubernetes), where the Service was the issue.

However, if I add a `peristentVolumeClaim` the Pod starts and data is added to the mounted directory (i.e., it is an nfs share, with mod 777 and user/group 1001:1001 ownership), but RedisInsight is not accessible anymore (local on the Pod and externally via the Service).

I used the similar `yaml` files for other deployments and there they worked as expected.

The RedisInsight logs are empty.

deployment.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: redis-insight
  name: redis-insight
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: redis-insight
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis-insight
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: redislabs/redisinsight:latest
        name: redis-insight
        env:
          - name: RIHOST
           value: 0.0.0.0
          - name: RIPORT
            value:  "8001"
          - name: RIHOMEDIR
            value: /db
          - name: RILOGDIR
            value: /db
        volumeMounts:
          - name: db 
            mountPath: /db
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8001
          name: redis-ui-port
      volumes:
        - name: db
          # emptyDir: {}
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc-nfs-redis-insight
```

service.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-insight-service-loadbalancer
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: redis-insight
  ports:
  - port: 8001
    targetPort: 8001
    protocol: TCP
    name: redis-ui-port
```

persistent-volume-claim.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc-nfs-redis-insight
spec:
  storageClassName: nfs
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

persistent-volume.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-nfs-redis-insight
  labels:
    type: nfs
spec:
  storageClassName: nfs
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    path: /srv/redis-insight/
    server: nfs.local
    readOnly: false
```

data dir on nfs-server (exported as `srv/redis-insight`):

```bash
/mnt/redis-insight$ ls -aln
total 24
drwxrwxrwx 6 1001 1001 4096 Okt 22 15:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 1000 1000 4096 Okt 22 15:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 1001 1001 4096 Okt 22 15:17 bulk_operation
drwxr-xr-x 2 1001 1001 4096 Okt 22 15:17 dropbox
drwxr-xr-x 2 1001 1001 4096 Okt 22 15:17 profiler_logs
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001    0 Okt 22 15:17 queries.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001    0 Okt 22 15:17 redisinsight.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001    0 Okt 22 15:17 redisinsight.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 1001 1001 4096 Okt 22 15:17 rsnaps
```

Comment: not sure if this is related as i would need to see your logs, but i had to run redis-insights as root to get it to work with a pvc (runAsUser: 0). btw, you'll probably want to change your deploy strategy to "Recreate"

Comment: @ericfossas: Thank you for the suggestion, however, changing `runAsUser` did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described [here](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/write-permissions-on-volume-mount-with-security-context-fsgroup-option/16524/4) it is not a RedisInsight issue. Rather the issue emerged from NFS `PersistentVolume` not supporting the Pod `SecurityContext`.

I could resolve my issue by using [csi-driver-nfs](https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/csi-driver-nfs) instead. Detailed installation instructions can be found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/csi-driver-nfs/blob/master/docs/install-csi-driver-v4.1.0.md).

Answer (score 0):

I am a Product Manager at RedisInsight, we will look into this issue in this ticket in RedisInsight repository:
https://github.com/RedisInsight/RedisInsight/issues/1315